# Wicket AJAX does not respond after dom changed by JavaScript

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.6, wicketstuff

Wicket AjaxSubmitLink onSubmit is not called after applying appendJavascript which changes the DOM of a page. Sample code is:

```
add(new ListView("list", someArrayList){
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
                add(new AjaxSubmitLink("link") {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                         target.appendJavascript("swap('"+this.getMarkupId()+"')");
                     });
})
```

The JavaScript looks like:

```
function swap(markupId){
    var one = $('.dashed').first().parent();
    var two = $('#'+markupId).parent();
    var tone = one.clone();
    var ttwo = two.clone();
    one.replaceWith(ttwo);
    two.replaceWith(tone);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really sure, you left a lot of code out (html? hwere is your JS included?). My guess is that you are swapping something with the `markupId` of the AjaxSubmitLink. Try an `alert` with the `id` first or use a debugger to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method causing the problem. According the documentation it does not clone event handlers. Try `clone(true);`

You could also handle the swap server side and then rerender the list after the swap. That would be the Wicket way to do it.